# Instead of using the redux can I use a global javascript object to sore all my app state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to react and redux not sure about how the immutable object helps the react rendering faster ? what are disadvantages application state object is not immutable?

Comment: It is easier to compare immutable objects on React Component renders. 
You can use plain JS object to store state, but then you should tell your components that their props have changed (you can call `forceUpdate` method of components)

Comment: Immutable objects are not about performance, they are about predictable state of application.

Comment: If you are not sure you need redux, you can concentrate the application state into the root component of your app. Or you can also spread the application state across the app components. You should avoid keeping the app state into a global object, otherwise you will lose one of the best features of React, which is the re-rendering of components on state or props change.